# $U(24)$: internal direct product and generators of a subgroup of a full symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, sagemath

I'm being confused by the following question:

*Build a permutation representation of U(24). List a representation of each element. Then, construct the group as a subgroup of a full symmetric group created with three generators. To determine these three generators, you will likely need to understand U(24) as an internal direct product.*

I think that my permutation representation of $U(24)$ is correct (checked in Sage). However, I'm not sure to see the link between understanding $U(24)$ as an internal direct product and determining the three generators to build the subgroup of a full symmetric group - $S_8$ here.

For now, I have the following two subgroups, which look to build $U(24)$ as an internal direct product:

$$
H = \{ 1, 5, 7, 11 \} \\
K = \{ 1, 13 \} \\
\text{we have: } U(24) = H \times K \text{ such that: } H \cap K = \{ 1 \}, hk = kh \text{ for all } k \in K \text{ and } h \in H
$$

Is this the right way to proceed? What is then the link with generators?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $U(24)\cong C_2\times C_2\times C_2$, see

[What group is $(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ isomorphic to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013692/what-group-is-mathbbz-24-mathbbz-isomorphic-to).

Generators of $U(24)$ in $S_8$ are given by
$$
(1234)(5678), (15)(26)(37)(48), 
$$
see [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Ejwilson/math/8/C2xC2xC2.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is clearing things up! I understand that all elements of $U(24)$ have order 2, pointing to the isomorphism with $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.
How do you obtain $(1234)(5678)$ as a generator though? Using $\{ 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23\}$ coded as $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$, since $2$ is of order 2, how can it map to $3$ and not to $1$? (i.e. $5^2 \mod 24 = 1 \neq 7$)

Comment: "Coded as" is a misunderstanding. The group is $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ and $C_2=\{e,g\}$ with $g^2=e$. The numbers $1,2,\ldots ,8$ refer to the group $S_8$ of bijections of the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,8\}$. For example, if you take $g=(15)$, then $g^2=e=(1)$. Now consider the subgroup of $S_8$ generated by the product of transpositions $(15)(26)(37)(48)$ and the product of two $4$-cycles $(1234)(5678)$. Which group do you obtain?